# How the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Calculated Field works?

Tags: javascript, calculated-field, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to understand how the Calculated Field in CRM 2015 works? Actually how it gets implemented in backend? Which kind of technology it is using, JavaScript or anything else?

I have also noticed that if I have the Calculated Field on a CRM view, and it holds the value of DiffInDays() formula (= Date value - current Date), the value of the field will get refreshed automatically daily even I don't refresh the view. How does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript required, performed server side, from [Calculated and rollup attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817863.aspx).

> Calculated attributes are calculated in real-time when they are
>   retrieved.
>
> Because rollup attributes persist in the database, they can be used
>   for filtering or sorting just like regular attributes. Any kind of
>   process or plug-in will use the most recently calculated value of the
>   attribute. Rollup attribute values are calculated asynchronously by
>   scheduled system jobs.